# .htaccess ignore query_string adword

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to ignore a google adword get that is coming through.

Url coming in as:

```
/location/&gclid=287ejek22kj
```

This is going to a 404 page because of the gclid...

I need it to go to:

```
/location
```

I've tried this, with no success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)&gclid=(.*)$  $1 [L]
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

```
192.168.1.2 - - [01/May/2011:05:38:48 +0100] [192.168.1.2/sid#938b98][rid#2789a40/initial] (3) [perdir C:/HTTP/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/HTTP/htdocs/location/&gclid=287ejek22kj -> location/&gclid=287ejek22kj
192.168.1.2 - - [01/May/2011:05:38:48 +0100] [192.168.1.2/sid#938b98][rid#2789a40/initial] (3) [perdir C:/HTTP/htdocs/] applying pattern '^(.*)&gclid=(.*)$' to uri 'location/&gclid=287ejek22kj'
192.168.1.2 - - [01/May/2011:05:38:48 +0100] [192.168.1.2/sid#938b98][rid#2789a40/initial] (2) [perdir C:/HTTP/htdocs/] rewrite 'location/&gclid=287ejek22kj' -> 'location/'
```

Check your rewrite log. See [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and `RewriteLogLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks alright but you can also try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^&]+)&gclid=.*$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you pls paste relevant lines of apache's access and error log when this request is sent.